# Deploying Scala web apps

Tags: web-services, scala, deployment, war

I know that WAR files aren't recommended for Scala apps.  What's the best way to web enable and deploy a Scala based web app or web service?

Comment: Really depends on what framework/library you used.  There's no one answer.

Comment: Somebody said Docker :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Ryan. It really depends on which framework u are using.

Normally in backbone framework like unfiltered, we need to use plugin sbt-assembly to generate a fat jar, which includes all dependencies we need and also points to the main Scala file for the app. Thus we can use jar -jar ...  However, we still need wrap it into bash file, record pid file and so on.

For the play framework app, it is easy to deploy. we can use command "activator dist" to deploy. Play will generate a zip file which contains almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sbt native packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager) plugin, which allows you to package you app and have [Java Server Application](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/archetypes/) option.